# Hundred separator in Libre office calc number formating / Indian number formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, openoffice-calc, currency-formatting

I am moving to Open office spreadsheets and I need to handle large financial values in spread sheet cell.

By default libre office provide NUMBER & CURRENCY format, where "," is used as per Indian Numbering system(refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system )

However, I don't need the number till one's unit place. I need to see number in crore.

26,75,73,350 should be shown as 25.76

Libre office only provide "," as thousand separator. This separator follow US counting system, i.e. millons etc. If used as user-defined format "0.00,,"

I see cell value as 267.57 and not 26.76

What is a good user-defined format following Indian counting system?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this, N4 contains the value 12345678

=ROUNDUP(N4/("1" &**REPT(0,LEN(N4)-2)**),2)

Result 12.35

You can changethe bold section with a fixed value 10000 or so

Answer (score 0):

With a formula it would just be a matter of dividing by 10000000 (ten million) and showing decimal places to suit. Unfortunately Open Office Calc (like most other popular spreadsheet programs) does not provide such a format by default. However in a custom format `,` effectively divides by 1000 (one thousand) and `%` multiplies by 100 (one hundred) so `267573350` with a User-defined format of:

```
 0.00,,,%
```

looks like `26.76%`. The underlying value is however retained, so for example adding `1` to such a cell (in a different cell of general format) would show   `267573351`.

That is about as close as I can get just with formatting, but since `%` (ab)used this way is so open to confusion you might want to give some visual warning by say appending `"C"` to the format (`0.00,,,%"C"`) to show:

```
  26.76%C
```